# How to convert multiple columns datatype format to another datatype formats at a time in Pandas without mentioning column names?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, strftime

I have  dataframe with more than 20 columns having `datetime64[ns]` format. I want to convert them all into `stringtime`. Is there an easy way doing that.

```
Data.dtypes
LT_TOTAL                    float64
INSERT_DT            datetime64[ns]
M0_ACT_0400          datetime64[ns]
M0_ACT_0500          datetime64[ns]
M2_ACT_1100          datetime64[ns]
M1_ACT_1240          datetime64[ns]
M3_ACT_1305          datetime64[ns]
M4_ACT_1400          datetime64[ns]
M5_ACT_1600          datetime64[ns]
M6_ACT_2990          datetime64[ns]
M7_ACT_3000                  object
```

**Normal way**

```
data.loc[:,'M4_INI_1400'] =data.loc[:,'M4_INI_1400'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Currently if there are 20 columns , I need to repeat this statement 20 times. I am looking for an alternative easy way.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is select columns having dtype `datetime64`. Slice them out, `stack` and call `dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` and `unstack` and assign them back

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('datetime64').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].stack().dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').unstack()
```

*Note*: on big dataframe, I don't know about the speed of this method.

Answer (score 4):

I think if use `apply` with default `axis=0` it loop by columns, so it should be faster like `axis=1` with loop by rows:

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes('datetime64')
df[df1.columns] = df1.apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```